# zsh autocomplete: "soco" --> "somecommand.sh"

Tags: zsh, oh-my-zsh

Is it possible to configure zsh (and/or oh my zsh) to perform autocompletion as follows?

I type `soco` and it expands to `somecommand.sh`.

Because this matches:

```
somecommand.sh
^^  ^^
```

Answer (score 0):

That's the `_approximate` completer.

E.g.

```
zstyle ':completion:*' completer _extensions _complete _approximate
```